# Laravel rewriting routes/htaccess url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I need some help with redirecting url routes. Currently, I have http://website.com/subpage/123 and I want to redirect it to http://website.com/subpage/new+title. I basically want to redirect the page id (123) to the page title (new+title) which is urlencoded. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try registering another route.

1st route:

```
Route::get('subpage/{id}', function($id) {
    // Get page based on id
});
```

2nd route:

```
Route::get('subpage/{slug}', function($slug) {
    // Get page based on slug
});
```

You should use a controller of course, this is just an routing example